# Product of sheaf homs

Tags: sheaf-theory

*Sorry if this has already been answered somewhere, but I can't find it if it has.*

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space, and $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ two sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

Is there some nice way of simplifying $$\mathcal{H}\mathrm{om}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})\otimes \mathcal{H}\mathrm{om}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G})?$$

If needed, we can assume that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free, and possibly (but ideally not) that $\mathcal{G}$ is locally free.

Comment: If $\mathcal{F}$ is locally free, your sheaf is isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\otimes\mathcal{G})$. Is this the simplification you wanted ?

Comment: @Roland yes, this was exactly what I wanted! (thanks for answering both of my questions by the way)